# Unity Facebook API Bug (only shows up on Android 6.0+): Facebook is logging in with old accounts on a fresh apk install without asking

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently running into an issue with steps to reproduce this bug as follows:

1. Install the app
2. Login with Facebook
3. Uninstall the app
4. Reinstall the app using the same apk
5. Logout of Facebook and into a different Facebook account
6. Open the app and login with Facebook
7. Should see the old user account being logged in automatically
   instead of asking to create a new user account, or logging into a
   different account.

The only fix I've seen for this issue so far is to delete all the app data on the device (or at least the cache), which clears this issue. It appears that the Android OS is holding on to cache even after the app is uninstalled. I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this in my app by clearing the Facebook data on startup. Unfortunately I can't find a way in the Facebook API to do this, unless I'm missing something. We have the concept of a guest user in our app, so ideally I can detect if it's a guest user and delete all previous Facebook data on startup.

For more information: This is a Unity Android application using the Facebook Graph API

Comment: So ... what is the question? Or this this a bug report that should probably rather go to https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: and maybe you could force a [`FB.Logout`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Logout) on starting your App?

Comment: The question is: how do I remove all Facebook tokens and credentials from a freshly installed app, since Android 6.0 and greater holds onto your cache even after you uninstall an app.  That's kind of what I'm getting at, but does FB.Logout remove any Facebook info that's stored in cache?